# How to support trigger-dependent visuals while maintaining the control's basic behavior?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this custom control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNs.MyControl"
    <Border DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
        <Grid Margin="5,0,5,0">
            ...
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ControlData.DependencyPropertyOne}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ControlData.DependencyPropertyTwo}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ControlData.DependencyPropertyThree}" />
            ...
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

I use it as follows:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNs.ParentControl"
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type my:MyControl}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Border Background="Red" BorderThickness="6"></Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <my:MyControl ControlData="{Binding CdOne}"/>
        <my:MyControl ControlData="{Binding CdTwo}"/>
        <my:MyControl ControlData="{Binding CdThree}"/>
        <my:MyControl ControlData="{Binding CdFour}"/>
        <my:MyControl ControlData="{Binding CdFive}"/>
        <my:MyControl ControlData="{Binding CdSix}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

But when I hover with the mouse, the content is replaced with red background (all the `TextBlock`s disappear).

So how to allow the host control to change some trigger-dependent visuals while maintaining the control's basic behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `override the ControlTemplate of MyControl` on `IsMouseOver`, so actual template containing your content won't be shown.

Ideally this trigger should have been inside MyControl. But, even though you want to do from outside, you need to add `ContentPresenter` inside border which will host your content.

Replace ControlTemplate inside style with this one:

```
<ControlTemplate>
   <Border Background="Red" BorderThickness="6">
       <ContentPresenter
            Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}"
            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentTemplate}"
            ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentStringFormat}"
            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}"
            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.VerticalContentAlignment}"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your triggers need to either be inside your `UserControl`, or your `UserControl` needs to have dependency properties (eg. "BackgroundBrush") that external things can set via triggers and which your control will honour when rendering itself. This is what the `TemplateBinding` is useful for.

Effectively anything using your control should have no idea of the template inside it, and should just be setting public properties.

If you really want to separate your control's logic from its appearance, then you should create a proper lookless `Control`, rather than a `UserControl`, and consumers can supply their own control templates as they want. This is the approach that the standard WPF controls take.